# AngularJS + Scrollify doesn't scroll normally after disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been using Scrollify to do the main page of my site. However when changing to another route, Scrollify does not disable and keeps on trying to scroll to sections that were at another route. When using "$.scrollify.disable();" on page load, it disables Scrollify, however does not re-enable the normal scrolling. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently "scrollbar: false," in the option has caused this. Deleting this line will fix the error (not really the solution but the best thing I found).